# How to send parameters to Action from javascript function?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple view that show a table of data, I want to sort one of its columns when the header is clicked by AJAX, I'm new to AJAX and JS, so this was my try in the view:

```
<table id="tbl" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="getData('desc')" id="sort">Title</a>
        </th>
        <th>
            Author
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</table>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(getData('asc'))
        function getData(sort) {
            var srt = sort;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Book/BooksData/' + srt,
                dataTtype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#tbl > tr").remove();
                    $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                        $('#tbl').append('<tr><td>' + val.Title + '</td><td>' + val.Author.Name + '</td></tr>')
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

but when I click the header the `sort` parameter goes null in the action,

```
public JsonResult BooksData(string sort)
{
    var books = new List<Book>();
    if (sort == "asc") books = db.Books.Include(b => b.Author).OrderBy(b => b.Title).ToList();
    else books = db.Books.Include(b => b.Author).OrderByDescending(b => b.Title).ToList();

    return Json(books, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Yes I'm doing it wrong, but I revised it many times, I can't see logical error except that passing parameters in JavaScript is different than C#

Comment: Unless you have defined a specify route for `"Book/BooksData/{sort}`, then you need to add the value as a query string value, not a route value

Comment: Yes, I forgot that :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simpliest way.You need to concatenate `sort` value to `url`, using `query` string.

Now, when you click header the sort parameter must goes with your value in the action.

Please try this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/Book/BooksData?sort=' + srt,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
          $("#tbl > tr").remove();
          $.each(data, function (index, val) {
              $('#tbl').append('<tr><td>' + val.Title + '</td><td>' + val.Author.Name + '</td></tr>')
          });
      }
});
```

Another way is to use this:

```
url: '@Url.Action("BooksData","Book")?sort=' + srt
```

The `@Url.Action` returns just a string.

In `Razor` every content using a @ block is automatically HTML encoded by `Razor`.

Comment: Thanks, It works,
It seems forgot about the query string!

Comment: @MohamedAhmed, don't forget to accept my answer in order to help other people.

Comment: Is it possible in JS to write something like: `var xx=zz=="foo"?"bar":"bar2"`

Comment: @MohamedAhmed, yes, it is possible. It is called `conditional (ternary)` operator.

Comment: Or as designed `url: '@Url.Action("BooksData","Book")', data: { sort: srt }, ....`